# (Wordpress) - PHP variable to show custom field hyperlink

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, hyperlink

I have authors associated with particular books, and where there is more than one author, I needed to comma delimit them. I have done this using the PHP implode function, but I cannot get it to show a string of author names, hyperlinked (I'm having trouble setting the variable correctly).

This is the code I originally had, which shows the authors names, linked to their respective pages, but was not comma delimited (no implode).

```
<?php if(get_field('author')): ?>
        <?php foreach(get_field('author') as $related): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($related->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($related->ID) ?></a>&nbsp;
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

This is the code I now have, which comma delimits where there are multiple values, but does not dsplay the authors names correctly:

```
<?php foreach(get_field('author') as $related);
$author = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'author' ); 
$authorString = implode (',' , $author);
echo $authorString; 
?>
```

I think I need to edit the '$author = ' variable to include the

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($related->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($related->ID) ?></a>
```

bit of the old code. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use `implode` at all? Can't you just use a counter and echo a comma if the counter is greater than zero? Like that:

```
<?php if(get_field('author')): ?>
    <?php $i = 0; foreach(get_field('author') as $related): ?>

        <?php if($i > 0) { echo ",&nbsp;"; } ?>

        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($related->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($related->ID) ?></a>

    <?php ++$i; endforeach;  ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That way you can use your working code.

Comment: Thanks vstm, that works perfectly! I was under the impression that implode was what I needed to use. I'm far more comfortable with what you suggested.

Comment: Do you know how I might alter it to include '&' where appropriate?

For example:

1 author - x

2 authors - x & x

3 authors x, x & x

Thanks

Comment: @Rob: Well the first thing to remember is that `&` alone is not valid HTML - you have to escape it to `&amp;` otherwise some browsers might discard it. Then of course it depends on which positions are "appropriate" - you can perhaps use the `$i`-counter to check which separator to print. If it's more complicate than that you probably have to be more precise and maybe edit the question and add more details.